# Spring Boot Framework doesn't initialize Database on Startup

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a problem with the Spring Framework. It doesn't create the database automatically on startup. I read the [HowTo-Guides of Spring on how to initialize the database](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html) and followed these steps, but it doesn't work. I also searched around the web for similar problems, but I didn't find anything which could help me.

**Error description:**

On startup of the Server, I get an Errormessage:

`FATAL: Datenbank »money_man_api_db« existiert nicht` (German)

`FATAL: Database »money_man_api_db« does not exist` (English translation)

**My configuration:**

*application.properties:*

```
server.port=3000

# Basic Connection Configuration
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=20000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5

# PostgreSQL Configuration
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/money_man_api_db
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=admin
```

Why doesn't the database get initialized? Did I forget something?

Comment: Springboot isn't going to auto-create the database for you. You need to create the DB yourself. But Springboot can auto-create tables in the DB. You already have property for this: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto.

Comment: In this case the title of the HowTo-Guide is really misleading, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should create a database, later on you can connect to this database.

The title is misleading because Hibernate will not create a database, but will create the tables in this database. Hibernate is an ORM, it will create compatible SQL queries to interact with the database.
It's a layer between your OO code and the database, that takes care of complexity of creating SQL queries and mapping them to your code.

More info can be found here: https://hibernate.org/orm/